# how to find untranslated Strings in Android Studio 2

Tags: android, android-studio

How to find untranslated i18n strings (`string.xml`) in a new Android Studio 2.0?

I'm looking for something like `Refactor > Remove Unused Resources...`

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on this? What does `i18n` mean?

Comment: @Vucko it is well known numeronym for internationalization :) http://www.i18nguy.com/origini18n.html

Comment: you've just googled it, admit it :D im kidding, sorry bro :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There sure is.
You can access the Translations Editor by opening a `strings.xml` file for editing and clicking the **Open editor link**, or clicking the globe icon   [image] in the Design layout view and choosing Edit Translations.

[image]

If you open the editor, you will have highlighted in red all the keys for the strings that are **not translated** to all the languages present in your project.

[image]

In all honesty, I had no idea this even existed, so I'm happy I had better luck finding it than you did, hope it's what you're after.